UUID issues with Swift and Core Data
I'm having an error at runtime related to the UUID in my code. Let me explain whats attached. Below are the Persistence Controller, DeflectionLogEntity, DeflectionLogViewModel, and the main issue, DeflectionLogsView. Together these create the list of deflection logs in DeflectionLogsView_Preview. At one point I had the issue solved but the button in DeflectionLogsView was causing issues. Please, if there is anything someone can do to help it would be much appreciated. As UUID is the main issue I'll put those portions in the post but ill attach all the files incase more context is needed, as well as the crash report. One of the largest issues I'm having as a new swift user is finding where to look for the error. If there are any insights into debugging the code that would be helpful.
The list from DeflectionLogsView
List(viewModel.deflectionLogs) { log in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(deflectionLog: log)) {
                        HStack {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text(log.logName ?? "New Log")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .bold()
                                Text(log.logDescription ?? "New Log Description")
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Text(log.logDate.formatted()) // Assuming you want to format the date
                        }
                    }
                }

The persistence controller:
static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let controller = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = controller.persistenceContainer.viewContext
        
        // Sample data setup for preview
        for i in 1...5 {
            let log = DeflectionLogEntity(context: viewContext)
            log.id = UUID()
            log.logName = "Test Log \(i)"
            log.logDescription = "Description for test log \(i)"
            log.logDate = Date()
        }
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return controller
    }()
    
    // Core Data container configuration
    lazy var persistenceContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YarderPro")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return container
    }()

From DeflectionLogsViewModel, fetchDeflectionLogs and addDeflectionLog:
func fetchDeflectionLogs(sortedBy key: String = "logDate", ascending: Bool = true) {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<DeflectionLogEntity> = DeflectionLogEntity.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: key, ascending: ascending)]
        
        do {
            deflectionLogs = try viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to fetch deflection logs: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // Add a new deflection log
    func addDeflectionLog() {
        let log = DeflectionLogEntity(context: viewContext)
        log.logName = "New Log"           // Set default values directly
        log.logDescription = "..."
        log.logDate = Date()
        log.id = UUID()
        
        saveContext()
    }

Here are the relevant files:
DeflectionLogsViewModel.swift
and DeflectionLogEntity.swift
Please Help I'm desperate!!!
What Ive Tried:
I tried changing the instances of DeflectionLogEntity to make sure the UUID was non-null, this didn't do anything be a UUID is inherintly non-null. I put in some error handling, but this didn't help. The same problem is erroring: a crash resulting from UUID._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC. This error also happens when I run it in the app simulator, thus I think it has to do with something other than the preview code.  The best I can do to trace the error is below, the foundation.UUID file errored at line 51 with message "Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x180b6ef1c)"
 0x180b6ef00 <+168>: strb   w10, [x19, #0xd]
    0x180b6ef04 <+172>: strb   w11, [x19, #0xe]
    0x180b6ef08 <+176>: strb   w8, [x19, #0xf]
    0x180b6ef0c <+180>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x50]
    0x180b6ef10 <+184>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x40]
    0x180b6ef14 <+188>: add    sp, sp, #0x60
    0x180b6ef18 <+192>: ret    
->  0x180b6ef1c <+196>: brk    #0x1
    0x180b6ef20 <+200>: brk    #0x1
    0x180b6ef24 <+204>: mov    x8, #-0x2000000000000000  ; =-2305843009213693952 
    0x180b6ef28 <+208>: stp    xzr, x8, [sp, #0x18]
    0x180b6ef2c <+212>: add    x20, sp, #0x18


I downloaded and ran your project without any issues. Perhaps you could delete the database file and start fresh if that is possible. I did see some strange things in your code like initialising the view model twice and using different versions of the managed context in the view

Thank you @JoakimDanielson for your input, re-cloning the project made it so that I could run it in the simulator which was incredibly helpful. However, I'm still having the same issues running it in the preview. Do have any idea what could be causing this issue.
